# (Flutter) Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException in turn by turn mapBox navigation

Tags: android, flutter, mapbox, turn-by-turn

I'm trying to import turn by turn mapBox navigation in my flutter app. I'm following this sample for achieving the desired navigation but it gives error when i run it:

[Turn By Turn navigation](https://github.com/Imperial-lord/mapbox-flutter)

But when i try to execute the navigation, I'm getting this error:

```
    E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785): Module loading failed
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mapbox.navigation.trip.notification.internal.MapboxTripNotification.<init> []
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2363)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1759)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.common.module.provider.MapboxModuleProvider$noArgConstructorCreator$1.getInstance(MapboxModuleProvider.kt:107)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.common.module.provider.MapboxModuleProvider.createModule(MapboxModuleProvider.kt:69)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigation.<init>(MapboxNavigation.kt:179)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigationProvider.create(MapboxNavigationProvider.kt:23)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.fetchRoute(NavigationActivity.kt:107)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.onNavigationReady(NavigationActivity.kt:94)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.updateNavigationReadyListeners(NavigationView.java:653)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.access$700(NavigationView.java:75)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView$1.onStyleLoaded(NavigationView.java:247)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.notifyStyleLoaded(MapboxMap.java:963)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.onFinishLoadingStyle(MapboxMap.java:225)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapView.java:1383)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapChangeReceiver.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapChangeReceiver.java:198)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(NativeMapView.java:1166)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:179)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785): Module loading failed
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: INSTANCE
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1635)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.common.module.provider.MapboxModuleProvider$kotlinObjectReferenceProvider$1.getInstance(MapboxModuleProvider.kt:117)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.common.module.provider.MapboxModuleProvider.createModule(MapboxModuleProvider.kt:69)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigation.<init>(MapboxNavigation.kt:179)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigationProvider.create(MapboxNavigationProvider.kt:23)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.fetchRoute(NavigationActivity.kt:107)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.onNavigationReady(NavigationActivity.kt:94)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.updateNavigationReadyListeners(NavigationView.java:653)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.access$700(NavigationView.java:75)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView$1.onStyleLoaded(NavigationView.java:247)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.notifyStyleLoaded(MapboxMap.java:963)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.onFinishLoadingStyle(MapboxMap.java:225)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapView.java:1383)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapChangeReceiver.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapChangeReceiver.java:198)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(NativeMapView.java:1166)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:179)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785): Module loading failed
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mapbox.navigation.trip.notification.internal.MapboxTripNotification.getInstance []
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2103)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1724)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.common.module.provider.MapboxModuleProvider$singletonReferenceProvider$1.getInstance(MapboxModuleProvider.kt:126)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.common.module.provider.MapboxModuleProvider.createModule(MapboxModuleProvider.kt:69)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigation.<init>(MapboxNavigation.kt:179)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigationProvider.create(MapboxNavigationProvider.kt:23)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.fetchRoute(NavigationActivity.kt:107)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.onNavigationReady(NavigationActivity.kt:94)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.updateNavigationReadyListeners(NavigationView.java:653)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.access$700(NavigationView.java:75)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView$1.onStyleLoaded(NavigationView.java:247)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.notifyStyleLoaded(MapboxMap.java:963)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.onFinishLoadingStyle(MapboxMap.java:225)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapView.java:1383)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapChangeReceiver.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapChangeReceiver.java:198)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(NativeMapView.java:1166)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:179)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785): Module loading failed
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.common.module.provider.MapboxModuleProvider$defaultMapboxModuleCreator$1.getInstance(MapboxModuleProvider.kt:138)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.common.module.provider.MapboxModuleProvider.createModule(MapboxModuleProvider.kt:69)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigation.<init>(MapboxNavigation.kt:179)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigationProvider.create(MapboxNavigationProvider.kt:23)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.fetchRoute(NavigationActivity.kt:107)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.onNavigationReady(NavigationActivity.kt:94)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.updateNavigationReadyListeners(NavigationView.java:653)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.access$700(NavigationView.java:75)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView$1.onStyleLoaded(NavigationView.java:247)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.notifyStyleLoaded(MapboxMap.java:963)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.onFinishLoadingStyle(MapboxMap.java:225)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapView.java:1383)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapChangeReceiver.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapChangeReceiver.java:198)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(NativeMapView.java:1166)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:179)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: it.sistematica.coride: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:464)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.trip.notification.internal.MapboxTripNotification.createPendingOpenIntent(MapboxTripNotification.kt:275)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  at com.mapbox.navigation.trip.notification.internal.MapboxTripNotification.<init>(MapboxTripNotification.kt:112)
E/MapboxModuleProvider(30785):  ... 24 more
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785): Exception in onDidFinishLoadingStyle
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785): MapboxInvalidModuleException(type=NavigationTripNotification)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.mapbox.common.module.provider.MapboxModuleProvider.createModule(MapboxModuleProvider.kt:88)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigation.<init>(MapboxNavigation.kt:179)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigationProvider.create(MapboxNavigationProvider.kt:23)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.fetchRoute(NavigationActivity.kt:107)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.onNavigationReady(NavigationActivity.kt:94)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.updateNavigationReadyListeners(NavigationView.java:653)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.access$700(NavigationView.java:75)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView$1.onStyleLoaded(NavigationView.java:247)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.notifyStyleLoaded(MapboxMap.java:963)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.onFinishLoadingStyle(MapboxMap.java:225)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapView.java:1383)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapChangeReceiver.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapChangeReceiver.java:198)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(NativeMapView.java:1166)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:179)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(30785):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
W/System.err(30785): MapboxInvalidModuleException(type=NavigationTripNotification)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.mapbox.common.module.provider.MapboxModuleProvider.createModule(MapboxModuleProvider.kt:88)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigation.<init>(MapboxNavigation.kt:179)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigationProvider.create(MapboxNavigationProvider.kt:23)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.fetchRoute(NavigationActivity.kt:107)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.dormmom.flutter_mapbox_navigation.activity.NavigationActivity.onNavigationReady(NavigationActivity.kt:94)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.updateNavigationReadyListeners(NavigationView.java:653)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView.access$700(NavigationView.java:75)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView$1.onStyleLoaded(NavigationView.java:247)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.notifyStyleLoaded(MapboxMap.java:963)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.onFinishLoadingStyle(MapboxMap.java:225)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapView.java:1383)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapChangeReceiver.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapChangeReceiver.java:198)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(NativeMapView.java:1166)
W/System.err(30785):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err(30785):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
W/System.err(30785):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:179)
W/System.err(30785):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
W/System.err(30785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
W/System.err(30785):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
W/System.err(30785):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
E/libc++abi(30785): terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::PendingJavaException
F/libc    (30785): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 30785 (tematica.coride), pid 30785 (tematica.coride)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'OPPO/CPH2273EEA/OP4F97:12/SP1A.210812.016/R.202209022301:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2022-12-05 12:43:33.054383583+0100
Process uptime: 0s
Cmdline: it.sistematica.coride
pid: 30785, tid: 30785, name: tematica.coride  >>> it.sistematica.coride <<<
uid: 10000
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::PendingJavaException'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000007841  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007ff8d27830
    x4  736f646277641f73  x5  736f646277641f73  x6  736f646277641f73  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  00000077998682c0  x10 ffffff00fffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 0000000000232a3a  x13 00000019bb91d520  x14 00321163fa4d57a0  x15 000000004cec4ec5
    x16 000000779992cbb0  x17 0000007799908450  x18 00000077a30a0000  x19 00000000000000ac
    x20 0000000000007841  x21 00000000000000b2  x22 0000000000007841  x23 00000000ffffffff
    x24 0000007ff8d27970  x25 0000007ff8d279b0  x26 000000764f7bf968  x27 000000764f7bf960
    x28 000000764f7bf980  x29 0000007ff8d278b0
    lr  00000077998b9b6c  sp  0000007ff8d27810  pc  00000077998b9b9c  pst 0000000000000000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000078b9c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+180) (BuildId: f24f65acf653c409ca4332aced817a71)
      #01 pc 0000000000373aa4  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #02 pc 0000000000373c14  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #03 pc 00000000003711d4  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #04 pc 0000000000370800  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #05 pc 000000000037075c  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (__cxa_throw+112) (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #06 pc 0000000000094680  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #07 pc 00000000000aee88  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #08 pc 0000000000115b8c  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #09 pc 00000000001c3898  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #10 pc 00000000001c3314  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #11 pc 00000000001c5b70  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #12 pc 000000000022177c  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #13 pc 00000000000fb3e0  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #14 pc 000000000021b0c4  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #15 pc 000000000021a930  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #16 pc 000000000021a9fc  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #17 pc 0000000000219c24  /data/app/~~c1v49E5YOUU4cpsgsZkXMA==/it.sistematica.coride-dE8WRurv1omhuSOzQwOqGg==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so (BuildId: 5340fab4c92fd87f8304775de4bc95627e863fd7)
      #18 pc 0000000000016bb0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+912) (BuildId: 0c269320029489b4040b2307f9282499)
      #19 pc 00000000000167b8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112) (BuildId: 0c269320029489b4040b2307f9282499)
      #20 pc 000000000014d19c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+44) (BuildId: f58022602a4be6b7ee457879f2b1e56f)
      #21 pc 00000000001b542c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+108) (BuildId: 8e7b80fce423e4224a2848a1fa52e8ed4313c088)
      #22 pc 0000000002006d0c  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+204)
      #23 pc 0000000002008f48  /memfd:jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Looper.loopOnce+168)
```

My pubspec.yaml

```
name: codrive_flutter
description: Codrive with flutter framework
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.5.0
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_mapbox_navigation: ^0.0.25
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.0.4
  location: ^4.4.0
  google_fonts: ^2.3.1
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  dio: ^4.0.4
  mapbox_gl: ^0.15.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
```

My build.gradle

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "it.sistematica.coride"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-telemetry'
}
```

Any suggestions about how to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried closing and rebuilding the app?

Comment: I tried to do this but the error is present yet

Comment: try with upgrading     compileSdkVersion 33 & targetVersion 33

Comment: Done, bu also with this change I'm getting the error

Comment: hello map box is not compatible for flutter and react native i had a talk with technical support of mapbox team.

Comment: @Dhruv Sakariya Do you have my same problem? What's do you suggest me?

Comment: from my side i have to transfer project to native android and ios.

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/4967#issuecomment-974244529) was fixed in native Android version of mapbox SDK

> Closing as the fix is available in `v2.0.2`, `v2.1.0-rc.2`, and will be available in the upcoming `v1.6.2`. Thanks for reporting the issue!

The flutter library is not maintained properly, but my guess if you use the latest version `0.26` it will work

```
flutter_mapbox_navigation: ^0.0.26
```

There is a lot of changes to Android in this version

if not, try to change mapbox version from android build gradle [file](https://github.com/eopeter/flutter_mapbox_navigation/blob/master/android/build.gradle) manually, until it works for you

```
com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.2.1
```

Comment: Nothing has changed using ^0.0.26, then when I tried to add any version (2.8.x,2.7.x,2.6.x, ...) of com.mapbox.navigation:android in my build gradle I got: :Failed resolution of: Lcom/mapbox/navigation/core/fasterroute/FasterRouteObserver;